# For any linearly independent vectors, there exists a homogeneous linear equation system with those vectors as a basic solution system

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_s$ be $s$ vectors which are linearly independent. Prove: there exists homogeneous linear equation system with $n$ unknowns such that $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_s$ is a basic solution system.

Can you understand my expression?

Hints?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your vectors live in ${\bf R}^n$ for some $n$.

Let $V$ be the subspace of ${\bf R}^n$ they generate. Let $W$ be the subset of ${\bf R}^n$ consisting of all the vectors perpendicular to all the vectors in $V$ ($x$ perpendicular to $y$ means the dot product $x\cdot y$ is zero). Prove that $W$ is a vector space. Let $\{\,w_1,w_2,\dots,w_r\,\}$ be a basis for $W$. Consider the system $w_i\cdot x=0$, $i=1,2,\dots,r$.